# Image is not centered in ActionPage on android wear device 320x320

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

In android-wear application I have an ActionPage with images. On devices with 280x280 resolution images are placed in center of circle, but on devices 320x320 images are shifted (see screenshots).

```
    <android.support.wearable.view.ActionPage
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/action_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:color="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:rippleColor="@color/kis_primary_color"
        app:imageScaleMode="fit"
        />
```

If set app:imageScaleMode="center" image is placed in center, but white circle fills whole screen.

Image is set in java code:

```
    public abstract class ButtonFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, 
                final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_button, container, false);
            final ActionPage actionPage = (ActionPage) root.findViewById(R.id.action_page);
            actionPage.setImageResource(getImageResourceId());
            return root;
        }
```

ActionPage on 320x320 need to be look like on 280x280. Any ideas?[image]
[image]
[image]